# apim context.response.statusreason availability?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm including context.Response.StatusReason in my APIM policy. This is getting populated for errors.  For example, a 404 error will return a value of "OperationNotFound" as the context.Response.StatusReason.  However, for <inbound> logging I would expect the StatusReason value to be "Success" but it's empty. Does APIM only populate StatusReason for certain status codes?

Answer (score 0):

StatusReason is populated in a three ways:

1. In case of errors APIM sets appropriate status code and status reason.
2. By set-status policy.
3. When response is received from backend APIM copies status code and reason from backend response before executing outbound policy.

Do you by any chance try to log it in inbound policy? When operation was identified successfully but no response is received yet context.Response would be initialized with a default status code of 200, but empty reason.